# How could I manipulate HasMany relationship with difference of foreign key and primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have `User model and Comment model`, each user has many comments

To look up the owner of a comment, you need to  Find the user uid which matchs the author_id of the comment.

How could  I set the has_many relation in Mongoid?

Is it possible to avoid `N+1 query`, when I loaded all comments first then add the user.name for each comment? Thanks

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :user #, foreign_key: :uid ????
  field :post_id, type: String
  field :author_id, type: Integer
end


class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_many :comments
  field :uid, type: Integer
  field :name, type: String
end
```

Comment: Why not call the `:author_id` as `:user_id` as per convention?

Comment: I want to do that,but I could not.the data in db are imported by other modules which was written by outsourced .so I need other uncommon methodology to do so.thank you